# CSS image disappears too fast

Tags: html, css, image, delay

I have a gif which shows when page loads but it won't work. My code appears to be ok, by my point of view.  I have tried several times to modify, add, delete from code but it did not work. I have added img src to div loader but then preloader appeared for only couple milliseconds. Not even a second.

```css
#loader-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
    z-index: 9999;
    /* makes sure it stays on top */
}
#loader {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
    top: 50%;
    /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
    background-image: url("images/Preloader_1.gif");
    /* path to your loading animation */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    /* is width and height divided by two */
}
```

```html
<div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your looking to have a gif animation loading when the page is loading, you need to use JavaScript. In the below snippet I've provided simple jQuery that shows a gif when the page is loading, then shows the body of the HTML

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#loader').delay(500).fadeOut();
    $('#loader-wrapper').delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
  });

  $('body').show();

});
```

```css
#loader-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
    z-index: 9999;
    /* makes sure it stays on top */
}
#loader {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
    top: 50%;
    /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
    background-image: url("http://img.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/77443320c6509d6b500e288695ee953502ecbd6d_m.gif");
    /* path to your loading animation */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    /* is width and height divided by two */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
  <p>hello</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, it works partially, it shows  only a few miliseconds.

Comment: Yes, thats because the page only took a few miliseconds to load. If you have a page with lots of content (images etc) then it will obviously take longer

Comment: vestigedayz.com/Lucius-Payne/ro this is Live Demo. I've tried to do what you helped me but result was the same as now.

Comment: Well how can I make in that script to take longer?

Comment: You modify the .delay(xxx) values in the javascript code. If you set it the .delay(3000) it will take 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds) before it fades away

Comment: Right now it is only taking 0.5 seconds (500 milliseconds) to fade away

Comment: Thanks for clarification.